# Avoid typing really much arguments?

Tags: c++

```
void logVar(var a) {
    var z;
    z = a.toString();
    printf("%s ", z._chr().getUtf());
}

void log(var a, 
    var b = argIgnore, var c = argIgnore, var d = argIgnore,
    var e = argIgnore, var f = argIgnore, var g = argIgnore,
    var h = argIgnore, var i = argIgnore, var j = argIgnore,
    var k = argIgnore, var l = argIgnore, var m = argIgnore,
    var n = argIgnore, var o = argIgnore, var p = argIgnore,
    var q = argIgnore, var r = argIgnore, var s = argIgnore,
    var t = argIgnore, var u = argIgnore, var v = argIgnore,
    var w = argIgnore, var x = argIgnore, var y = argIgnore,
    var z = argIgnore, var A = argIgnore, var B = argIgnore
    )
{
    logVar(a);  
    if (b.type != varIgnore) logVar(b);
    if (c.type != varIgnore) logVar(c);
    if (d.type != varIgnore) logVar(d);
    if (e.type != varIgnore) logVar(e);
    if (f.type != varIgnore) logVar(f);
    if (g.type != varIgnore) logVar(g);
    if (h.type != varIgnore) logVar(h);
    if (i.type != varIgnore) logVar(i);
    if (j.type != varIgnore) logVar(j);
    if (k.type != varIgnore) logVar(k);
    if (l.type != varIgnore) logVar(l);
    if (m.type != varIgnore) logVar(m);
    if (n.type != varIgnore) logVar(n);
    if (o.type != varIgnore) logVar(o);
    if (p.type != varIgnore) logVar(p);
    if (q.type != varIgnore) logVar(q);
    if (r.type != varIgnore) logVar(r);
    if (s.type != varIgnore) logVar(s);
    if (t.type != varIgnore) logVar(t);
    if (u.type != varIgnore) logVar(u);
    if (v.type != varIgnore) logVar(v);
    if (w.type != varIgnore) logVar(w);
    if (x.type != varIgnore) logVar(x);
    if (y.type != varIgnore) logVar(y);
    if (z.type != varIgnore) logVar(z);
    if (A.type != varIgnore) logVar(A);
    if (B.type != varIgnore) logVar(B);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(0);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same with less typing?

The option is to generate this entire code from a script. (That's the only way to be sure there are no typos survived).

UPDATE:

I think I should have given much more detail in my question. I never seen a question getting 7 downvotes in just a couple of minutes.

The `var` class I am using is a JavaScript like class for my own library, the instance of `var` can hold either number or a string or an array or an object, or boolean. It has a constructor which can construct from any of those types and some more, including `enum special { argIgnore }`.

So when constructor `var::var(special)` is called, (which is the default for `log()`, the variable is considered ignored. This allows to use the `log()` function like this:

```
var a = 1;
var b = "hello";
var c = arr;
c.push(100);
c.push(200);
log(a, b, c, 500, "world");
```

This call will print:

```
1 hello 100, 200, 500, world
```

Using varargs/stdargs is not possible here, because varargs cannot call constructors on arguments.

Using vectors or other sort of preset structures is not useful for my case, because this is a syntactic sugar what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, use a container like `std::vector` or `std::map` (whichever one is better suited).

Comment: How would I use `log(3, "hello")` with `std::vector`?

Comment: With something like `std::vector<var> args{{3, "hello"}}; log(args);`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, of course I can pass in an array or a vector or just call log for each parameter, but my goal is different so those solutions are not matching my question.

Comment: Hanging on to the requirement of passing 28 arguments to a function is just plain ridiculous. If you want to log a variable number of arguments use something more idiomatic like overloading stream operators. Since there appears to be a few missing details (like asinine requirements) I'm close-voting this as too broad.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I admit I am stretching C++ to do something it was not designed to do (JavaScript-like syntactic sugar), but this exactly narrows my question. Most of 28 arguments are invisible and there are no performance limitations since this is just a casual console output. So maybe you could consider removing your close-vote, because I think I have explained all weirdness that of course is present in my question.

Comment: CaptainObvlious is correct. Simply making the log function take in a single argument of `vector<var>` might be what you want--if you [wrap your arguments in curly brackets](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e396faf6b56f9552), and every one of them is convertible to `var`, they will be interpreted as an initializer list for the `vector<var>` argument, which will be constructed from them and passed in. Of course, this is in c++11 and later, and you might as well use Yakk's solution since that's cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

This does much the same thing.  Extra work is done in case you pass in things that can be converted to `var` but are not `var`.  About the only difference is any such temporary `var` have a shorter lifetime.

```
// acts on a `var` if it is not `varIgnore`:
template<class F>
void on_var( var const& v, F&& f ) {
  if (v.type != varIgnore)
    std::forward<F>(f)(v);
}
// logs 1 or more vars out:
template<class...Vars>
void log(var a, Vars&&...vars) {
  logVar(a);
  // this strange syntax runs the on_var for each
  // argument in the ...vars parameter pack by expanding
  // the pack into an array of integers (all full of 0s), which
  // is then discarded.  The array creation has no side effects, so
  // under any optimization settings, the array isn't actually created,
  // but the operations are still done.  C++1z has improved ways
  // to do this:
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(
    on_var(std::forward<Vars>(vars), [](var const&v){logVar(v);})
  ,0)...};
  printf("\n");
  fflush(0);
}
```

if things convertible to `var` are not valid parameters, a simpler solution works:

```
template<class...Vars>
void log(var a, Vars...vars) {
  logVar(a);
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(
    (vars.type != varIgnore)?(logVar(vars),0):0
  )...};
  printf("\n");
  fflush(0);
}
```

with no need for `on_var` function.  However, your clarification seems to indicate that things-converted-to `var` have to work.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58c8f0664ff07663).

`var` is written as an example "any type of variable" class with a meaningful `toString`.  I modified `logVar`, but the modifications shouldn't matter much.

Comment: This must be c++11, because compiler barks a lot.

Comment: `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
  (void)discard{0,(
        ~~~~~~~^
`

Comment: @exebook I fixed some errors.  And yes, it is C++11; this is 2015.  Barring a specific version request in your question, I'm going to use the current C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestions

I feel this is a much more simpler and OOP approach than the templates approach, although I see someone did a nice job at a template version :)

Its much more common and considered best-practice to use a class for the argument list than a large list of variables. As you have already experienced, it is a difficult to maintain and use.

My suggestion would be change the interface of `logvar()`

Instead of this:

```
logvar(var a, var b, ...)
```

You would probably thank yourself later to change this to:

```
logvar(LogData& data)
```

Then you could have a class `LogData` that held all your variables and you can handle the logic without changing the interface. If you ever need to add or remove a variable, it is done in `LogData` and not in the function argument list.

#### Personal Feeling about default arguments

I prefer default arguments after something has been implemented and I come back and realize there should be something else, this can be a great place-holder when you are in a pinch and need to get something done.... But it makes it difficult for the next person who comes along because its one more little thing that isn't obvious in the code when you are reading and happen to encounter it being used.

Comment: Of course this is considered best-practice, but my question is how to make something unseen before, which is `log(a, b, c);` and in fact this is just to replace `printf("%%%", a, b, c)`. And though I appreciate your answer, and I acknowledge that your answer is correct in it's intention to teach the best way of doing things, it is not answering *my* question.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks :)